# OSGi: What happens to existing instances when its source (class) bundle is updated?

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, osgi-bundle

The general question: what happens to an existing instance when its source (class) bundle is updated (and the framework refreshed)?

For instance, let's say i have an instance of a class (Class A, instance-a), then i change the source for Class A in its bundle (Bundle A), then i update bundle-A and Refresh the framework. Does instance-a, created before the update, somehow 'magically' have the updated functionality of new Class A?

Likewise, if i have Class B instance-b (from bundle B), and Class B extends Class A (from Bundle A), then i change/update/refresh bundle A as above, would the already created instance-b have the functionality from new Class A?

It seems the answer to both of these is NO. It seems that, as a general rule, for extant instances, they have to be RE-INSTANTIATED (discarded and new instances created) to get the new functionality. Is that TRUE?

Thx.

Comment: 'Re-instantiated' is the wrong term. What i mean is that the previous instances simply have to be discarded, and new instances created to gain the updated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic. If you hold an instance of a type from a bundle and that bundle is updated, the instance you hold is unaltered.

This is why you should use services for using instances of another bundle. The bundle registers a service, you get the service. If the bundle is stopped, its services are unregistered and you can be notified. Using Declarative Services and its annotations makes this all quite easy.